# Why won't my Mustang move in 1st, 2nd, 3rd gear after clutch change?

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, mustang

My mustang will not move in first or second or 3rd gear but will in 4th gear. I really need some advice regarding the issue. It is rattling when the pedal isn't engaged.

I recently paid for a new kit (clutch, pressure plate, throw out bearing, pilot bearing, all came in the clutch kit I provided to the shop) to be installed but clearly, something was halfway done.

This time I'm going to do it all myself. I recorded my issue so please view it an give me an opinion of what you think 
Link-https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KUdHV14u6SE

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you said you "paid for a new kit to be installed", what do you mean by "kit"?

Comment: Clutch , pressure plate,throw out bearing,  pilot bearing , all came in clutch kit I provided to the shop

Comment: Are you sure the gearbox itself is ok? Is 4th a direct connection between primary shaft and output shaft while 1,2 and 3 are via the layshaft - which could mean the layshaft has a problem especially as you mention the noise made. You may need to have the transmission checked...

Comment: I'd also wonder along those lines if it was moving in those gears before the clutch install.